# Python, TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable error

Tags: python, python-typing

I am using python 3.8 to make a sudoku solver

```
from __future__ import annotations
Matrix = list[list[int]]
```

In this line that defines Matrix there is this error which I cant fix how can I fix this?
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is complaining because `list` is a type, and, in this context, `list[...]` is trying to subscript that type.

You need to use `list[list[int]]` as a type annotation, not as a value to be assigned:

```
Matrix: list[list[int]] = []
```

Note also that Python 3.8 natively supports type annotations, but using the `typing` module instead of native types, so you can do this instead:

```
from typing import List
Matrix: List[List[int]] = []
```